# Estou tentando salvar um arquivo em um caminho específico com VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Pra deixar mais fácil a explicação, vou estar chamando um arquivo de "A" e o outro arquivo de "B".

Basicamente, o que eu estou tentando fazer é copiar os dados do arquivo "A" para o "B".
Para isso, no próprio código eu crio um novo arquivo "B" e copio as informações pra ele.

No entanto, quando eu tento salvar o arquivo "B", ele dá o seguinte erro: Erro em tempo de execução '1004'.

A minha intenção é salvar o "B" em um local específico do computador, com um nome específico. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

**O código que eu tenho é esse:**

```
Sub tratamento()

'Aqui eu declaro as variáveis que eu vou usar
Dim base As Worksheet
Dim este_arq As Workbook, contemplados_arq As Workbook
Dim number As Integer, contagem As Integer
Dim data_atual As Date

Set base = Plan1
number = 1
contagem = 0

'Nesse loop ele faz a exclusão de linhas em branco na coluna "E"
With base
    .Range("A1").Select
    Do While ActiveCell <> ""
        If .Cells(number, 5) = "" Then
            .Cells(number, 5).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
            contagem = contagem + 1
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            number = number + 1
        End If
    Loop
End With

Set este_arq = ThisWorkbook

'Aqui ele copia as informações do meu arquivo atual
base.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

'Já aqui ele cria um novo arquivo, pra onde eu quero colar as informações copiadas
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set contemplados_arq = ActiveWorkbook

'Aqui ele cola as informações
contemplados_arq.Sheets(1).Paste

'E foi aqui que deu o problema: minha intenção é salvar o novo arquivo em um caminho específico com um nome específico.
'Mas dá erro.
contemplados_arq.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Contemplados hoje" & "\" & "Relatório.xlsm")
contemplados_arq.Close


End Sub
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Para aumentar suas chances de obter ajuda, você pode dizer qual foi a mensagem de erro, e não apenas o código do erro.

Comment: Eu já passei por uns erros na hora de salvar, mande aí a mensagem de erro. É somente "o método SaveAs do objeto Sheet falhou"?

Comment: Uma sugestão para depurar: adicione um ponto de parada na linha que dá erro, execute o código até ali e, então, faça manualmente a operação de salvar, exatamente como está descrita na sua linha de código (no seu caso, clicar em "Salvar como..." e escolher o caminho em questão. Se aparecer uma mensagem de erro ao tentar fazer manualmente, você já tem uma indicação de qual é o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado, César Rodriguez, Testei sua dica e me ajudou bastante! No final, na hora de salvar manualmente, também gravei uma macro e tentei entender o código da gravação e deu tudo certo. Valeu mesmo, cara!

Comment: Que bom! Abraço!

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação da propriedade [Workbook.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.path), lá diz *"Retorna uma Cadeia de Caracteres que representa o caminho completo para a pasta de **trabalho/arquivo** que este objeto de pasta de trabalho representa."*, verifique então se a expressão `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Contemplados hoje" & "\" & "Relatório.xlsm"` está retornando uma caminho válido.

Answer (score -3):

Tenta fazer isso aqui...

```
Diretorio = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Contemplados hoje\\"
Doc = "Relatório.xlsx"
Set Exemplo = contemplados_arq
With Exemplo
  .SaveAs (Diretorio & Doc)
End With
```

Dica: Pressione <kbd>CTRL + G</kbd> para abrir `Janela Verificação Imediata` e cole isso `?ThisWorkbook.Path` e pressione o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> para ver o caminho que ele está trazendo.

Answer (score -4):

Conforme vimos, o erro 1004 é um erro em tempo de execução que ocorre durante a execução de um código VBA. E todos os erros que discutimos acima são devidos a erros humanos ao escrever o código logo, seguindo os pontos acima você poderá corrigi-lo e até mesmo evitá-lo futuramente.

Deste modo, de maneira resumida podemos dizer que para a correção deste erro você deverá se atender aos pontos:

Faça uma execução de código passo a passo para ver em qual linha ocorre o erro.
Certifique-se de verificar todos os nomes das pastas de trabalho às quais você está se referindo.
Você também pode usar um código VBA para verificar se uma pasta de trabalho já está aberta ou não.
E use o método activate para ativar uma planilha antes de fazer referência a uma célula ou intervalo dela.

Comment: *"....E todos os erros que discutimos acima são devidos a erros humanos ..."*, que erros e onde foram discutidos? Por que frisar que são erros **humanos**? Alguma produção não humana aqui? *"...seguindo os pontos acima você poderá corrigi-lo..."*, que pontos? Acima onde? *"...Faça uma execução de código passo a passo para ver em qual linha ocorre o erro...."* o autor da pergunta já não indicou onde ocorre o erro?